# How to leave cells containing formula blank when input is blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

I have a list of number ranges (Start# to End#) as shown in the screenshot here below:

[image: example_1]

Through formulas, I am trying to automatically add the next 'start' number in line to column B (following the logic: current cell of col B = number in previous cell of col C + 1). I also need column C to show the 'end' number after entering the amount in the respective cell of column H (logic: current cell of col C = number in previous cell of col C + value in col H). I hope this makes sense to someone else, I'm starting to get confused myself.

What I have kind of works: `=C3+1` into `B4` and `=C3+H4` into `C4`, copied down the columns, but I don't want it to run the same numbers all the way to the bottom of the sheet (just empty if its possible). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Formula for B479: `=IF(AND(H479<>"",H479<>0),C478+1,"")`

Formula for C479: `=IF(B479<>"",SUM(H479+B479),"")`